# Add column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 variables (id, V1, V2), I would like to create another variable according to variables V1 and V2 which will be called V3 and which will take 2 modalities ("LISTED" and "UN_LISTED"). Here is my data frame:

```
print(df)
   id             V1       V2
0   1            NaN      NaN
1   2       QSINTSTK      NaN
2   3  1111GHGKJKIUH  122354H
3   4        FGHKLIH  123456K
4   5         FDUL12  237899M
5   6        VHKIOY3  784236A
6   7            NaN      Nan
```

Here is the condition to create V3:

If V1 and V2 is null then it is "UN_LISTED"

If V2 is not null then it is "LISTED"

If V1 is start with "QS" or "1111" then it is "UN_LISTED" otherwise it is "LISTED".

Here is my code :

```
def label_list (row):
if row['V1'] == np.NaN and row['V2'] == np.NaN:
    return 'UN_LISTED'

elif row['V2'] != np.NaN:
    return 'LISTED'

elif row['V1'] == "^QS" or row['V1'] == "^(1){4}" :
    return 'UN_LISTED'

else : 
    return "LISTED"

datatest.apply(lambda row : label_list(row), axis = 1)
datatest['V3'] = datatest.apply(lambda row : label_list(row), axis = 1)
```

But the result is wrong :

```
print(df)
   id             V1       V2     V3 
0   1            NaN      NaN  LISTED
1   2       QSINTSTK      NaN  LISTED
2   3  1111GHGKJKIUH  122354H  LISTED
3   4        FGHKLIH  123456K  LISTED
4   5         FDUL12  237899M  LISTED
5   6        VHKIOY3  784236A  LISTED
6   7            NaN      Nan  LISTED
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A note about the following solution:

You have overlapping conditions in your requirements, for example, it is possible for `V2` to not be null, but also for `V1` to start with `QS` or `1111` (which occurs in row 3), so you will need to set up your `np.select` in the order that you want to prioritize those conditions.

Using `np.select`:

```
c1 = df.V1.isnull() & df.V2.isnull()
c2 = df.V2.notnull()
c3 = df.V1.str.contains(r'^QS|^1111').fillna(False)

df.assign(V3=np.select([c1, c2, c3], ['UNLISTED', 'LISTED', 'UNLISTED'], 'LISTED'))
```

Output:

```
   id             V1       V2        V3
0   1            NaN      NaN  UNLISTED
1   2       QSINTSTK      NaN  UNLISTED
2   3  1111GHGKJKIUH  122354H    LISTED
3   4        FGHKLIH  123456K    LISTED
4   5         FDUL12  237899M    LISTED
5   6        VHKIOY3  784236A    LISTED
6   7            NaN      NaN  UNLISTED
```

Comment: Thank you, I will have to choose my constraints